# testcafe waiting for backend service to come up

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, wait, testcafe

We have a C/S-architecture, with Angular based front-end to be tested with TC. The back-end needs some time to come up, whilst the front-end is coming up very fast.

The result is that the first tests against the front-end fail, whereas the later tests run fine.

Because I don't want hard timed wait-cycles, I'm looking for an elegant method to make TC wait until the back-end is up. Some `npm` module?

Comment: I think I've found a solution:
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/tcp-ping
or
- https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-reachable

Comment: Since you found a solution, you can post it as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution has been found by the question author:

"[npmjs.com/package/tcp-ping](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tcp-ping) or - [github.com/sindresorhus/is-reachable](https://github.com/sindresorhus/is-reachable)"